# Foursquare location specific checkins

Tags: php, foursquare

I have a requirement where i need to pull in location specific Foursquare checkins onto a website. For example: If  i am on a page for location "Mumbai", all checkins for this location should be displayed in a box on this page. Does Foursquare real time API provide such feature?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is only available through the venue push API if you manage the venue in question. For privacy reasons, a real time feed of users checking in to a venue is not provided otherwise.

Comment: What if the checkins are public?

Comment: I want the checkins details base on the location irrespective of  OAuth consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of checkins for a venue from the Venue endpoint, but you cannot get a list of who checked in unless you manage that venue.